# Compiling and running somebody elses java code

Tags: java, compilation

I'm interested in compiling and running some java code that works with an api service I'm thinking about subscribing to.  I'm a bit of a newbie to java, and I've been trying to get it to work since this morning.  Now I'm wondering if anyone here would be willing to help point me in the right direction.

Inside the example folder that comes with all of the code, are the files,

```
RateService.jar
RateServiceExample.bat 
RateServiceExample.class
RateServiceExample.java
```

(I'm on a mac but the bat script doesn't have anything I've haven't worked with before)

I would like to first compile the code.  Inside the java file is the line,

```
import com.gain.rateservice.*;
```

I opened up the jar file and sure enough was the directory,

```
/com/gain/rateservice/
```

with files

```
Bup.class
Msg.class
Rate.class
RateService.class
RateServiceListener.class
Sys.class
```

I try

```
javac RateSerivceExample.java
```

And I get,

```
RateServiceExample is not abstract and does not override abstract method
OnRateServiceMSGMessage(com.gain.rateservice.Msg) in
com.gain.rateservice.RateServiceListener
public class RateServiceExample implements RateServiceListener {
```

I'm guessing I'm not getting it cause of my newbie-ness.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: javac -cp .\RateService.jar RateServiceExample.java ?

Comment: The class file is already there so try java -cp .\RateService.jar RateServiceExample

Comment: I then get an error saying that

Comment: package com.gain.rateservice does not exist import com.gain.rateservice.*;

Comment: -cp tells javac/java to include the jar in the classpath when it searches for needed classes. The error you describe indicates that it's still not finding com.gain.rateservice.

Comment: oh sorry I assumed you were on windows because of the bat file. Obviously the path should be -cp ./RateService.jar not .\RateService.jar

Comment: @Delicious Chris - it might be a bit distasteful, but perhaps you should learn to *read* BAT files.  The BAT file won't work on a Mac (obviously) but it will give you clues as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

In Java if you implement an interface, then you must implement all of the methods of that interface.  In your case, this error means that the RateServiceExample class is claiming to implement the RateServiceListener interface, but is not actually implementing all of the methods of the RateServiceListener class.

A short term solution that would just get your code to compile would be to remove the `implements RateServiceListener` from the class declaration.  So instead your class declaration will look like this:

```
public class RateServiceExample
```

But if you actually wish to implement that interface, you will have to fill in your RateServiceExample class with all those methods.  Make sense?

To learn more about Java interfaces and inheritance, you can go [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html).

Comment: can I pull the methods from .class file?

Comment: Unlikely, the error messages indicate the current code is wrong at source level, as opposed to having classpath configuration issues at compilation time. Probably some kind of version issue, like an out-of-date example.

Comment: So I have java version 1.6.0_24 (Mac) and the code is fairly old, maybe 2003.  Would it be worth while to trying to run older versions of java?

Answer (score 0):

Posting as answer so I can collect my reputation points:

```
javac -cp .\RateService.jar RateServiceExample.java
```

And the .class file is already there so you can probably run it directly:

```
java -cp .\RateService.jar RateServiceExample
```